# Set editing permissions per column, per user Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, google-sheets-data-validation

I have a Google Sheet that's being edited by 3 people, but each person needs to edit only one column. EX Red will edit red column; Blue will edit blue column and Yellow, well, yellow column hahaha.

How can I make that Red can't edit Yellow and Blue; Blue can't edit Red and Yellow, and Yellow can't edit Red and Blue?

I'm trying to avoid accidental changes. I tried with the Google Sheet menu where you can block columns, but it seems there is no way to block it the way I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- click on the column of your Red comrade
- select **Protect range**
- click on **Set permissions**

  [image: 0]
- enter the email address of your red comrade
- press **Done**

  [image: 0]
- repeat for Blue and Yellow comrade

Comment: I did this before posting my question, but didn't work. When I do this, Google tells I need to grant access to the file so Red user can edit. When I grant access, Red can edit Yellow and Blue. I tried blocking the whole sheet except one column. It works for Red, but when I try to do so with Blue or Yellow, it says the sheet is already blocked. :'(

Comment: @RobertodeNobrega well, yes by granting access all users will be able to edit the sheet but those dedicated columns will be editable only by respective users eg. one per column. in other words. RED will be able to edit everything + his column but not BLUE+YELLOW columns

Comment: hahahaha Know I got it.!! Thank you.!! It's working now. Thank youu..!!!

Comment: It worked very well, thanks!