# How do I do some data validation dropdown items can be selectable by only owner of the document?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets document which is shared with nearly thirty people and I added data validation dropdown to all the cells to not entering different values except I defined.

This data validation dropdown has nine items and I want to the fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth and nineth items can be selectable by only owner of the document. Can you please explain how I can do this?

Comment: _Is this possible?_ You didn't ask "how", just "whether" and this is important because it makes this a hypothetical question. I suggest that you read these questions (and their answers) to get the creative juices flowing. [Google Sheets : format a cell differently based on user viewing the sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17843873/1330560), and [Set editing permissions per column, per user Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133252/196152) . All other things considered, you might care to look into [APPS scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets doesn't include a built-in feature to limit who can select certain option from a data validation drop-down but you might extend Google Sheets by using Google Apps Script more specifically by using an on edit trigger, it might be a simple or an installable trigger.

To use Google Apps Script you should know the basics about JavaScript.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets